# How to query documents by date outside of range?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection `db.events`

Mongodb allows to make a query by date range (date0 < date1)

> db.events.find({date: {$gt: date0, $lt: date1}})

It works properly but I need also to make queries with a date outside of range, like in query

> db.events.find({date: {$or: [{$lt: date0}, {$gt: date1}]})

But last query is not allowed by mongodb **"Error: Can't use $or with Date."**

So, how to make such queries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or) goes at the top level of the query object:

```js
db.events.find({$or: [{date: {$lt: date0}}, {date: {$gt: date1}}]})
```